# Zombie Processes Appearing When I Spawn Processes

Tags: ruby, linux, process, zombie-process

I have a pieces of code where i spawn off children processes to make it more efficient. However, they appear to create all sorts of zombie processes which block sockets and bring down the site.

```
spawn(:method => :thread) do
   if @login_user.suggested_group_info.new_record?
       xxx
   end
end
```

1) Why is this creating zombie processes?
2) How could i write the code such that i make sure i kill the process before it becomes a zombie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to save the PID of the spawned process and execute the waitpid(2) system call upon it after it dies.  (I don't know how Ruby does this.)

Comment: Ruby does this pretty much as you'd expect.  spawn returns a pid; a call to Process.waitpid(pid) waits for the process to exit and then reaps the zombie.

Answer (score 2):

You can also trap for the child shutdown which will clean up the zombie process

```
trap("CLD") {
  pid = Process.wait
  puts "Child pid #{pid}: terminated"
}
```